# Simple For Loop / If Statement Scenario

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to work out the code to do something very simple and cant seem to make it happen.  Any help with this would be sincerely appreciated.

The scenario - please see the screenshot below: 
                                                                            [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0e0P.jpg)

What I am trying to do:

Loop through the rows and if the cell in the column labeled "STATUS" for that row says "DUE SOON" in that row, the data in the cells after the STATUS is cleared.  These cells are formatted to turn yellow if there is no data in them; alternately, if there is a "C", then they remain gray.  So, in a nutshell, if there is a DUE SOON in the STATUS cell, the next 10 cells turn yellow due to formatting for empty cells.

I have also tried using the "REMAINING" column cell and if the number is less than 15 then the same thing should happen - also without success. Either scenario will work.

I understand how to clear the cells, and how to loop through the rows using a for loop, but this task is a bit more complicated than my limited programming skills will allow, so could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you post the code that you have, so we can have a better idea as to how to help you as per [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To")?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want.

```
 Sub Deleteif()


Dim iCntr As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
   iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1").Select

For iCntr = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iCntr, "COLUMN NUMBER FOR THE COLUMN CONTAINING STATUS").Value = "DUE SOON" Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10)).Select
        Selection.Value = ""
        Cells(iCntr, 1).Select
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to have a go at this!